# How to sum results of a GROUP By

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add results of a MySQL GROUP BY but I have not been able to do it, this is my code:

```
SELECT country,SUM(visits) AS visits,SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, COUNT(1) AS total FROM stats GROUP BY country HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Attached image of my result of my code and what I would like to achieve with the:

[image]

I will also let capture my tables:

[image]

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to add rollup

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(country varchar(2),visits int);
insert into t values
('co',12),('co',20),
('us',15),('us',1),('us',1);

SELECT country,SUM(visits) AS visits,
            SUM(visits-1) AS repetidos, 
            COUNT(1) AS total 
FROM  t 
GROUP BY country with rollup 
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;

+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
| country | visits | repetidos | total |
+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
| co      |     32 |        30 |     2 |
| us      |     17 |        14 |     3 |
| NULL    |     49 |        44 |     5 |
+---------+--------+-----------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```